# How/where do TreeNode subclasses implement Product-related methods?

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I'm trying to get a grasp of the

```scala
org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode
```

class of Spark 2.0.0 source code, but found the Product part funny.

the definition begins as

```scala
abstract class TreeNode[BaseType <: TreeNode[BaseType]] extends Product {
```

then I inspected `trait Product` and could not figure out how does `TreeNode` get to know the statistics which method `ProductArity` or `ProductElement` of `trait Product` need.

I searched for a while and find out somebody pointing out that the scala compiler will figure out those statistics for `case class`, but the `TreeNode` is not a case class and I cannot find some protocol or hints that `Product` can get from the implementing class to get the needed numbers such as `ProductArity` returns.

So does anyone know what's behind the black magic?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> TreeNode is not a case class

But every non-abstract class extending `TreeNode` is. There could also be non-case classes which implement `productArity` and `productElement` manually, but I don't think there are any in Spark.

Comment: yep I can still accept it :P. One more thing: what is the intention of making `TreeNode` extending `Product`? If case classes are inheritable then can we design `TreeNode` to be an `abstract case class` or something like that?

Comment: You can inherit from case classes, but it rarely makes sense. And making `TreeNode` an `abstract case class` would behave very differently from what's desired.